# Multiple buttons/textviews on a single xml code

Tags: java, android, button, textview

I'm new to programming and have some questions.
I need buttons and textviews but I can't use xml layout because the positioning and number of those will depend on user interactions. Can I just use 1  (and same for textview) in xml to define my custom look and then reference them:

```
Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton)
Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton)
Button btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton)...
```

and then set text with `btn1.setText(txt1)...`

And how to make 2 buttons side by side each takes about 1/2 of screen width in java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to this community.
I just answered this in another post.
Don't know how to link to it.
So I'm reposting it here.

Try this code!
This should help give an idea.

activity_prac_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/display_txt"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rowCount="4">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linear_view">

    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_btn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_txt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here's the rest of code

```
 public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int count = 1;

List<Integer> gridArray;
private TextView myDisplayText;
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gridArray = new ArrayList<>();
    gridArray.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prac_main);



    findViews();


}
private void findViews(){

    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_grid);
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(4);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) gridLayout.findViewById(R.id.linear_view);
    linearLayout.setTag("1");
    Button myButton = (Button) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
    myButton.setTag("1");
    TextView myText = (TextView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_txt);
    myText.setText("1");

    myDisplayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_txt);


    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            TextView txt = (TextView) view;
            myDisplayText.setText("PRESS " + txt.getTag().toString());
            if(count < 24) {

                createView();
            }
            else{
                dialogBox();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void createView(){

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setId(Integer.valueOf(R.id.new_view_id));
    ll.setTag(String.valueOf(count+1));

    Button newBtn = createButton();
    newBtn.setId(Integer.valueOf(R.id.new_btn_id));
    newBtn.setTag(String.valueOf(count+1));

    TextView txtView = createText();
    txtView.setId(Integer.valueOf(R.id.new_txt_id));
    txtView.setTag(String.valueOf(count+1));
    txtView.setText(String.valueOf(count+1));

    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_grid);


   ll.addView(newBtn);
    ll.addView(txtView);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    gridLayout.addView(ll);



        count++;

}

private Button createButton(){
    Button myBtn = new Button(this);
    myBtn.setText(R.string.button_send);
    myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            TextView txt = (TextView) view;
            myDisplayText.setText("PRESS " + txt.getTag().toString());
            if(count < 24) {

                createView();
            }
            else{
                dialogBox();
            }
        }
    });


    return myBtn;
}
public void dialogBox() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GRID IS FULL!");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("DELETE",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_grid);
                    gridLayout.removeAllViews();
                    count = 0;
                    createView();

                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
private TextView createText(){
    TextView myTxt = new TextView(this);
    myTxt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);

    return myTxt;
}

}
```

As you can see ids were created in res -> values -> ids file.

when creating views dynamically id is the same for the views.

Each TextView share same id. Each Button share same id. each layout share same id.

Ids are only important to access the contents of views.

However the Tag is what makes each view unique to each other.

Hope this helps you out!

**do you know how to make an ids file**, you could set your own ids.

Sample:

```
<resources>
   <item name="new_view_id" type="id"/>
   <item name="new_btn_id" type="id"/>
   <item name= "new_txt_id" type="id" />
</resources>
```